# android studio,failed to down samples index check your connection

Tags: android, android-studio

I am in China, and I am using Android Studio.File->Import Sample..., Then Problem happens like follow:

failed to down samples index check your connection and try again!
how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're caught by the Great Firewall. As you may know, most of the Google services are blocked. The best solution is to use a VPN service.

Comment: In my case, antivirus suit lead to this problem. temporarily disabling it, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Configure-> Setting->System Setting->HTTP Proxy->Auto-detect proxy settings

http://blog.csdn.net/double2hao/article/details/50740093